# Recurrence Formulas for Higher Order Derivatives

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

We are given:

- $V(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+2x^2y-\frac{2}{3}y^3)$
- Values for $x, y, \frac{dx}{dt},$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$.
- $\displaystyle \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = -x-2yx$
- $\displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial y} = -y-x^2+y^2$

I need to use this information to construct recurrence formulas for any arbitrary $\displaystyle \frac{d^n x}{dt^n}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{d^n y}{dt^n}$.

This has actually already been done. My issue is that I have no explanation whatsoever for why the formulas are correct. Specifically, we have:
$$
\frac{d^{n+2}x}{dt^{n+2}} = -\frac{d^{n}x}{dt^{n}} - 2\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{d^{k}x}{dt^{k}} \frac{d^{n-k}y}{dt^{n-k}}\\
\text{and}\\
\frac{d^{n+2}y}{dt^{n+2}} = -\frac{d^{n}y}{dt^{n}} - \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{d^{k}x}{dt^{k}}\frac{d^{n-k}x}{dt^{n-k}} + \frac{d^{k}y}{dt^{k}}\frac{d^{n-k}y}{dt^{n-k}}\right)
$$

I have tried the product rule, chain rule, etc., and cannot seem to figure out where these recurrence relations are coming from. These arise in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.0130.pdf) paper (equations 13 and 14), but the authors do not explain how they were obtained. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because these formulas are not correct. The Leibniz product rule for higher derivatives is
$$
(fg)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}.
$$
Your formulas miss the binomial coefficient.

---

However, note that **in the cited paper** the series terms that are actually used in the referenced formulas are scaled by the factorial, $a_n=\frac{x^{(n)}}{n!}$ and $y_n=\frac{y^{(n)}}{n!}$ so that $x(t+\Delta t)=\sum a_n\Delta t^n$ etc. and the propagation formula follows from the Cauchy series product formula which is then compatible with the Leibniz product via $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.